# Align environment with multiple separated values

Tags: align

I'm attempting to display an equation separated into 3 columns as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I managed to create the above image using an abomination of non breaking spaces (~) which obviously looks like complete trash both in the editor and also in the document as they aren't aligned properly.

```
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Area~of~\Delta ABD}~~~~~~~~~~~~ &= ~~~~~~~~~~\mathrm{area~of~\Delta ABC}  ~~      &+ ~~~~~~~ \mathrm{area~of~\Delta ACD} \\
\frac{x*z*\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{2}~~~~~~~~~~~~ &= ~~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{x*y*\sin\alpha}{2} &+ ~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{z*y*\sin\beta}{2}
\end{align*}

Both sides are multiplied by 2:
\begin{align*}
    x*z*\sin(\alpha+\beta)~~~~~~~~~~ &= ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ x*y*\sin\alpha &+ ~~~~~~~~~~ z*y*\sin\beta
\end{align*}

Both sides are divided by $x*z$:
\begin{align*}
    \sin(\alpha+\beta)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ &= ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{y*\sin\alpha}{z} &+ ~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{y*\sin\beta}{x}
\end{align*}

As $\frac{y}{z}=\cos(\beta)$ and $\frac{y}{x}=\cos(\alpha)$ we get:
\begin{align*}
\sin(\alpha+\beta) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ &= ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \cos\beta*\sin\alpha &+ ~~~~~~~ \cos\alpha*\sin(\beta)
\end{align*}
```

I was wondering how you'd do this in a less horrible way?

Comment: as well as `~` avoid `\sin{(\alpha...` use `\sin(\alpha...` as  the `{` hides the mathopen `{` so you lose the intended spacing.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If centering the column contents and aligning the `=` and `+` symbols is important to you, I suggest you employ a four-column `array` environment along the following lines:

[image]

In addition to removing the unneeded (and counterproductive) pairs of curly braces around the arguments of `\sin` and `\cos`, I've also removed all instances of the multiplicative `*` symbol and replaced some `\frac` expressions with inline-math fraction equivalents.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % automatic text mode, left-aligned

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.667}
\begin{array}{@{} l @{\qquad\qquad} c @{{}={}} c @{{}+{}} c @{}}
& \textnormal{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABD}$} 
& \textnormal{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABC}$}
& \textnormal{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ACD}$} \\[0.5ex]
& \frac{1}{2}x z\sin(\alpha+\beta) 
& \frac{1}{2}x y\sin\alpha 
& \frac{1}{2}z y\sin\beta \\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}L}{Multiply both sides by 2:}\\
& xz\sin(\alpha+\beta) 
& xy\sin\alpha 
& zy\sin\beta\\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}L}{Divide both sides by $x z$:}\\
& \sin(\alpha+\beta) 
& (y/z)\sin\alpha 
& (y/x)\sin\beta \\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}L}{As $y/z=\cos\beta$ and $y/x=\cos\alpha$ we get}\\
& \sin(\alpha+\beta)  
& \cos\beta\sin\alpha 
& \cos\alpha\sin\beta\,.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you a lot for the help, I wasn't aware of the array environment but it sure seems useful.

Answer (score 7):

You could align like so, although your first "text" rows are rather wide so the aligned + look a bit spaced out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\text{Area of $\Delta ABD$} &= \text{area of $\Delta ABC$}&&+  \text{area of $\Delta ACD$} \\
\frac{x*z*\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{2} &=  \frac{x*y*\sin\alpha}{2} &&+  \frac{z*y*\sin\beta}{2}\\
\intertext{Both sides are multiplied by $2$:}
    x*z*\sin(\alpha+\beta) &=  x*y*\sin\alpha &&+  z*y*\sin\beta
\intertext{Both sides are divided by $x*z$:}
    \sin(\alpha+\beta) &=  \frac{y*\sin\alpha}{z} &&+  \frac{y*\sin\beta}{x}
\intertext{As $\frac{y}{z}=\cos(\beta)$ and $\frac{y}{x}=\cos(\alpha)$ we get:}
\sin(\alpha+\beta)  &=  \cos\beta*\sin\alpha &&+  \cos\alpha*\sin(\beta)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was looking for it to be more centered as in Mico's reponse but this is also great, the text commands also seem very useful so I'll be sure to make use of those in the future.

Comment: @Oliver no harm in accepting Mico's :-) Note I also almost commented on the `*` which is not usually used for multiplication. Also while array works here beware it is designed for setting matrices of values not aligned displays so ulike amsmath alignments is not setting up display style and spacing

Comment: Which character would normally be used for multiplication here? And I suppose you could get to something like Mico's out of your version by changing \begin{alignat*} from 2 to 1? Both are definitely useful, always nice to learn a new feature or 2.

Comment: @Oliver normally nothing as in Mico's, `xy\sin\alpha` is x times y times sin alpha. Or `\cdot` if a symbol is needed or `\times` in elementary texts

Comment: Ahh of course, didn't think that one through. Thank you a lot for the help though!

Comment: +1 for "no harm in accepting Mico's" answer. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest three ways to cope with this. The first one is similar to your approach; for the second I use centering of the middle column, so to minimize white space.

In the third case, no alignment whatsoever is sought: each formula has three parts and your readers will be able to match them in the various steps.

Please, avoid ∗ for multiplication.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\IEEEintertext}[1]{\noalign{#1\vspace{1ex}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Your approach}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABD}$} &= \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABC}$}
  &&+ \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ACD}$} \\
\frac{x z\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{2} &= \frac{x y\sin\alpha}{2} &&+ \frac{z y\sin\beta}{2} \\
\shortintertext{Multiply both sides by 2:}
xz\sin(\alpha+\beta) &= xy\sin\alpha &&+ zy\sin\beta\\
\shortintertext{Divide both sides by $x z$:}
\sin(\alpha+\beta) &= \frac{y\sin\alpha}{z} &&+ \frac{y\sin\beta}{x} \\
\shortintertext{As $y/z=\cos\beta$ and $y/x=\cos\alpha$ we get}
\sin(\alpha+\beta) &= \cos\beta\sin\alpha &&+ \cos\alpha\sin\beta\,.
\end{alignat*}

\section{With slightly different alignment}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCcCl}
\text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABD}$} &=& \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABC}$}
  &+& \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ACD}$} \\[1ex]
\frac{x z\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{2} &=& \frac{x y\sin\alpha}{2} &+& \frac{z y\sin\beta}{2} \\[1ex]
\IEEEintertext{Multiply both sides by 2:}
xz\sin(\alpha+\beta) &=& xy\sin\alpha &+& zy\sin\beta\\[1ex]
\IEEEintertext{Divide both sides by $x z$:}
\sin(\alpha+\beta) &=& \frac{y\sin\alpha}{z} &+& \frac{y\sin\beta}{x} \\[1ex]
\IEEEintertext{As $y/z=\cos\beta$ and $y/x=\cos\alpha$ we get}
\sin(\alpha+\beta) &=& \cos\beta\sin\alpha &+& \cos\alpha\sin\beta\,.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\section{An altogether different method}

We start from the fact that
\[
\text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABD}$} = \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ABC}$}
  + \text{Area of $\Delta\mathit{ACD}$}
\]
Writing down the formulas and removing the common denominator $2$ gives
\[
xz\sin(\alpha+\beta) = xy\sin\alpha + zy\sin\beta
\]
Now we can divide both sides by $xz$ to obtain
\[
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{y}{z}\sin\alpha+\frac{y}{x}\sin\beta
\]
However, by definition, $y/z=\cos\beta$ and $y/x=\cos\alpha$, so we finally get
\[
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\beta\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha\sin\beta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Third version is the way to go. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the great examples! I think all of them look great, though I may honestly have gone pretty overboard by alligning them as I quite enjoy the 3rd one. I'm experimenting with the different options currently as it's my first time typesetting in LaTeX, it's just my personal notes so if it turns out bad it isn't terrible. Others also mentioned the multiplication so I have already removed them though that obviously isn't shown in the post.